# Is there any way to create "mini" (very small chart) with Chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

I wonder if there's anyway to create mini-sized line chart with Chart.js? (No labels on any axis, 180px*60px)

Example attached.

Thanks.!

[mini line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiODY.png)

Answer (score 2):

So the solution is define this options set:

```js
{
              bezierCurve:false, //remove curves from your plot
              scaleShowLabels : false, //remove labels
              tooltipEvents:[], //remove trigger from tooltips so they will'nt be show
              pointDot : false, //remove the points markers
              scaleShowGridLines: true //set to false to remove the grids background
}
```

& define height & width to your chart :)